# Maven issue for org.dom4j - Unauthorized error in spring.io repository

Tags: spring, maven, dom4j, spring-io

I have this dependency setting in my pom.xml

```
<dependency> 
<groupId>org.dom4j</groupId>
 <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId> 
<version>2.1.1</version> 
</dependency>
```

When I run the build command, I get this error:

```
Failed to read artifact descriptor for dom4j:dom4j:jar:2.1.1: Could not transfer artifact dom4j:dom4j:pom:2.1.1 from/to spring-ext (https://repo.spring.io/ext-release-local/): authentication failed for https://repo.spring.io/ext-release-local/dom4j/dom4j/2.1.1/dom4j-2.1.1.pom, status: 401 Unauthorized -> [Help 1]
```

This was working just about two weeks ago and when I run it again yesterday, this error showed up.

I tried doing my own research in this problem and it seems its related to this:

https://spring.io/blog/2020/10/29/notice-of-permissions-changes-to-repo-spring-io-fall-and-winter-2020

but I've read replies and comments in that link, no one was able to provide a definite solution or explanation to this problem.

Is this is a Maven related error? where it should probably change/update its credentials connecting to spring. or can this be fixed by other alternatives?

Comment: You should consume artifacts from central repository instead of repo spring apart from that being disallowed for a long time...

Comment: Where have you configured that location for repositories?